# CISCO ASA ASDM Allow internal IP to access external IP

Tags: firewall, cisco-asa

I'm running ASDM 7.2 and have 2 servers on the same local ip range that can communicate ok. These 2 servers have external IP's and I need to get them communicating on the external IP's but this fails. I'm not able to ping either server using the external IP.

What rules do I need to add using the gui?

Thanks

Comment: Use the internal IPs or use DNS doctoring.

Comment: I can not use the internal IP for reasons that is beyond this post. DNS doctoring? I did setup a dns name on cloudflare but this still didn't work.